# Cannot convert from 'unsigned int *' to 'LPDWORD'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I have the following code:

```
size_t lufread(void *ptr,size_t size,size_t n,LUFILE *stream)
{ 
    unsigned int toread = (unsigned int)(size*n);
    if (stream->is_handle)
    { 
        DWORD red; 
        BOOL res = ReadFile(stream->h,ptr,toread,&red,NULL);
        if (!res) 
            stream->herr=true;
        return red/size;
    }
    if (stream->pos+toread > stream->len) 
        toread = stream->len-stream->pos;
    memcpy(ptr, (char*)stream->buf + stream->pos, toread); 
    DWORD red = toread;
    stream->pos += red;
    return red/size;
}
```

and here is the compiler error:

```
error C2664: 'ReadFile' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'unsigned int *' to 'LPDWORD'
```

and i don't understand because `DWORD red` is the same as `unsigned long red`
so in the function `ReadFile()` 4th parameter `&red` should be `unsigned long *`, shouldn't it?

Comment: `unsigned int*` and `unsigned long*` are not the same thing. `DWORD` should be `typedef`'d as `unsigned long`, not `unsigned int` - is there any possibility some header in your project redefined it?

Comment: @AndrewMedico I don't think so.. but i'll check thx

Comment: "My code won't compile" very rarely means "compiler bug". I'd guess that 99.999999999999999% of the time, the problem is **not** a compiler bug.

Comment: @KenWhite if I had a buck for every time I thought I found a "compiler bug" I'd be retired by now. That said it is possible to hit one, but it's extremely rare.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Agreed. It *is* possible, but highly unlikely (especially given the relative simplicity of the indicated code and the frequency of use of `DWORD` and `ReadFile`), I'd think. :-) (I'd settle for half of that buck, myself. I could have retired when I was pretty young, back when I thought every compiler error I couldn't immediately grasp was a "bug".)

Comment: @KenWhite, MarkRansom, you guys are super confident in your coding!  Every time I see a compiler error pop up, I always assume "dang, another Problem Between Chair/Keyboard, no doubt..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int` and `long` are considered different types, even though they are both integer types of the same size (under Microsoft). Pointers to different types cannot be converted without an explicit cast.

It appears you're not using the standard definition of `DWORD` but have substituted your own. Don't do that.